# How to pass a Yii2 model attribute to socket.io client js?

Tags: socket.io, yii2

I am using Yii2 and socket.io for sending notifications. I have a client.js file which should emit an id of newly connected user to server. 
The code responsible for this in my client.js is:

```
socket.emit('AddId', '<?php $model->id ?>');//of course it does not work but I need smth like this.
```

So how to pass a Yii2 model attribute to socket.io client.js?

Client.js code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8890');

    socket.emit('AddId', '<?php $model->id ?>');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want send info about an user  you could do this way

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

   var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8890');

   socket.emit('AddId', '<?php  echo Yii::$app->user->id ?>');

});
```

Comment: I tried as you proposed but it seems the php code does't want to execute. In command line I've got:
new client connected
new client <?php  echo test ?> added to CLIENTS list

Comment: I tried also to execute  <?php  echo test ?> <?php  echo "test" ?> <?php  echo \'test\' ?> but no success. What could be the problem?

Comment: Your file .is namefile.php ?

Comment: namefile.js. It works from file.php but is it possible to execute php code from .js file?

Comment: From js file is not possibile execute php but you can invoke via ajax a php file a obtainn the result from server ..

Answer (score 0):

In Yii2 inside my index.php view I wrote:

```
$test = 'My text';//here could be any text data, model attributes etc
<script>
    var test = "<?php echo $test ?>";
</script>
```

After this update I was able to use a variable (var test) in my notification.js.
notification.js is added also to AppAsset.php as following:

```
public $js = [
       'js/notification.js'
       ];
```

notification.js file:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

   var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8890');

   socket.emit('AddId', test);//test is a variable (var test) from index.php file

});
```